# Is there such thing as "apply" in python?

Tags: python, wolfram-mathematica

I wonder, is there a function in python -let's call it now `apply`- that does the following:

```
apply(f_1, 1) = f_1(1)
apply(f_2, (1, 2)) = f_1(1, 2)
...
apply(f_n, (1, 2,..., n)) = f_n(1, 2,..., n) # works with a tuple of proper length
```

Since it does exist in eg. *A+* and *Mathematica* and it used to be really useful for me.
Cheers!

Comment: How about googling "apply" and "Python"?  It's the first hit.

Comment: @ArminRigo I was using Bing, dude. :)) :P Im not sure how this stuff went out of my mind anyway. < bit embarrassed :) >

Comment: It's also the first non-sponsored Bing hit. But the first _overall_ (sponsored) Bing hit is "Python on the Macintosh". Apparently they assume that "apply" is a typo for "Applescript". How much stock does Microsoft still own in their sworn enemy? :)

Comment: Answerers: thanks for the explanations!

Comment: Amusingly enough, python actually has apply, under the name `apply`, in Python 2.x.  As `pydoc apply` notes it's been deprecated since 2.3.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python has language-level features for this, known as "argument unpacking", or just "splat".

```
# With positional arguments
args = (1, 2, 3)
f_1(*args)

# With keyword arguments
kwargs = {'first': 1, 'second': 2}
f_2(**kwargs)
```

Comment: Technically there's still an `apply` function, but it has been deprecated for a long time in favor of this approach. http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#apply

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `*` operator for the same effect:

```
f_1(*(1, 2)) = f_1(1, 2)
...
```

The expression following the `*` needn't be a tuple, it can be any expression that evaluates to a sequence.

Python also has a built-in `apply` function that [does what you'd expect](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#apply), but it's been obsolete in favor of the `*` operator since Python 2.3. If you need `apply` for some reason and want to avoid the taint of deprecation, it is trivial to implement one:

```
def my_apply(f, args):
    return f(*args)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yep, use the `*` operator on the list of arguments. For a practical example:

```
max(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)    # normal invocation
=> 5

max(*[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) # apply-like invocation
=> 5
```

Think of the second snippet as equivalent to `apply(max, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])`